# Custom filter in jinja2 using in bottle

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle

I try to define custom filter in jinja2 using [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf) (not flask). Suppose I want to define a `pandoc` custom filter. Regarding the [jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#custom-filters), I have to define it that way:

```
from bottle import jinja2_view as view, jinja2_template as template
from jinja2 import environment, filters

def pandoc_convert(s):
    return pypandoc.convert_text(s, format='md', to='html5')

@get("/foo")
def foo():
    return template('foo.html')

environment = jinja2.Environment()
# Putting my custom filter.
environment.filters['pandoc'] = pandoc_convert
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

In template `foo.html` I have

```
  {{ "This is *some* markdown" | pandoc }}
```

When I run bottle code, it gets me:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'pandoc'
```

but if you print `environment.filters`, then `'pandoc': <function pandoc_convert at 0x7f827e233040>}` appears in that print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Updated**)

This answer provided generic instructions for working with Jinja, but
it looks as if `bottle` has its own special way of doing things.  You
need to ignore the Jinja documentation about environments and filters,
and instead delve into the bottle source; specifically, the
[Jinja2Template](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L3925), which looks like this:

```
class Jinja2Template(BaseTemplate):
    def prepare(self, filters=None, tests=None, globals={}, **kwargs):
        from jinja2 import Environment, FunctionLoader
        self.env = Environment(loader=FunctionLoader(self.loader), **kwargs)
        if filters: self.env.filters.update(filters)
        ...
```

Note that the `prepare` method accepts a `filters` keyword argument for setting filters on the environment it creates.

The `jinja2_template` function, which is defined like this:

```
jinja2_template = functools.partial(template, template_adapter=Jinja2Template)
```

And lastly, the [template](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L4225) function, which includes:

```
    if tplid not in TEMPLATES or DEBUG:
        settings = kwargs.pop('template_settings', {})
        if isinstance(tpl, adapter):
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = tpl
            if settings: TEMPLATES[tplid].prepare(**settings)
        elif "\n" in tpl or "{" in tpl or "%" in tpl or '$' in tpl:
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = adapter(source=tpl, lookup=lookup, **settings)
        else:
            TEMPLATES[tplid] = adapter(name=tpl, lookup=lookup, **settings)
```

So, when you call `jinja2_template("foo.html")` (which is what you're
doing), this becomes:

```
template("foo.html", template_adapter=Jinja2Template)
```

And within the `template` function, template will call the `prepare`
method of `Jinja2Template` with keyword arguments from `settings`,
which comes from the `template_settings` argument to `template`. So,
we can use a custom filter like this:

```
import bottle


def hellofilter(value):
    return value.replace("hello", "goodbye")


@bottle.get("/foo")
def foo():
    settings = {
        "filters": {
            "hello": hellofilter,
        }
    }
    return bottle.jinja2_template("foo.html", template_settings=settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=7070, debug=True)
```

If my template `foo.html` looks like this:

```
This is a test. {{ "hello world"|hello }}
```

Asking for `127.0.0.1:7070/foo` will return:

```
This is a test. goodbye world
```

If we didn't want to pass the `template_settings` argument every time
we call `jinja2_template`, we could use `functools.partial` ourselves
to create a wrapper for the `jinja2_template` function:

```
import bottle
import functools


def hellofilter(value):
    return value.replace("hello", "goodbye")


template_settings = {
    "filters": {
        "hello": hellofilter,
    },
}
template = functools.partial(
    bottle.jinja2_template, template_settings=template_settings
)


@bottle.get("/foo")
def foo():
    return template("foo.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=7070, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but with params it does not work: how do you transform `return template('foo.html', entries=mylist)`? What do you mean for "you have defined an appropriate loader for your environment" ?

Comment: See my update, which provides instructions specific to `bottle`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work. This works in general but in my *real* situation, I get the error `'Post' object has no attribute 'encode'` with Post is a class from frontmatter

Comment: The best path forward might be to open a new question, and include code that reproduces the error you're asking about.